# Confused about python logging with config file (only logs what is set for root_logger in config file)

Tags: python, logging

I (now) have the following code:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig


def function1():
    logger = logging.getLogger('function1')
    logger.debug('Debug')
    logger.info('Info')
    logger.warning('Warn')
    logger.critical('Critical')


def main():
    fileConfig('test_log.conf')
    logger = logging.getLogger('main')
    logger.debug('Debug')
    logger.info('Info')
    logger.warning('Warn')
    logger.critical('Critical')
    function1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I have the following config file:

```
[loggers]
keys:root,log1

[handlers]
keys:consoleHandler,rotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys:logFormatter

[logger_root]
level:INFO
handlers:rotatingFileHandler,consoleHandler

[logger_log1]
level:DEBUG
handlers:rotatingFileHandler, consoleHandler
qualname:main
propagate=1

[handler_consoleHandler]
class:StreamHandler
formatter:logFormatter
args:(sys.stdout,)

[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=NOTSET
args=('logs/Log.log', 'w', 5000)
formatter=logFormatter

[formatter_logFormatter]
format:%(asctime)s - %(name)s -%(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

When I run, I get the following output:

```
2020-03-23 19:16:30,529 - main -DEBUG - Debug
2020-03-23 19:16:30,529 - main -DEBUG - Debug
2020-03-23 19:16:30,530 - main -INFO - Info
2020-03-23 19:16:30,530 - main -INFO - Info
2020-03-23 19:16:30,530 - main -WARNING - Warn
2020-03-23 19:16:30,530 - main -WARNING - Warn
2020-03-23 19:16:30,530 - main -CRITICAL - Critical
2020-03-23 19:16:30,530 - main -CRITICAL - Critical
2020-03-23 19:16:30,531 - function1 -INFO - Info
2020-03-23 19:16:30,531 - function1 -WARNING - Warn
2020-03-23 19:16:30,531 - function1 -CRITICAL - Critical
```

I have given each of the loggers names and I still have the same problem

## original post:

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    import logging
    from logging.config import fileConfig
    fileConfig('logging.conf')
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.debug('Debug')
    logger.info('Info')
    logger.warning('Warn')
    logger.critical('Critical')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I have the following config file:

```
[loggers]
keys:root,log1

[handlers]
keys:consoleHandler,rotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys:logFormatter

[logger_root]
level:INFO
handlers:rotatingFileHandler,consoleHandler

[logger_log1]
level:DEBUG
handlers:rotatingFileHandler, consoleHandler
qualname:main
propagate=1

[handler_consoleHandler]
class:StreamHandler
formatter:logFormatter
args:(sys.stdout,)

[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=NOTSET
args=('logs/Log.log', 'w', 5000)
formatter=logFormatter

[formatter_logFormatter]
format:%(asctime)s - %(name)s -%(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

When I run, I get the following output:

```
2020-03-23 18:13:54,950 - tedCheck.main -WARNING - Warn
2020-03-23 18:13:54,950 - tedCheck.main -CRITICAL - Critical
```

What I was expecting was that no matter what the root_logger was set to, I could over-ride it in the specific log section for the function/method of the config file.

What good is having the section if it is going to do whatever the root_logger is set to?  My guess is that my config file is hosed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This line gets the root logger in the hierarchy, specifically:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

If you don't want the root logger, then you need to pass a name

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name="main")
```

Note that with your existing configuration, a propagating log1 and console/file handlers configured for root as well, you will likely see duplicate log events.

Comment: I added some more test code with logger names and am still having the same issue (see code above)

Comment: @jordanthompson You're not having the same issue, we can clearly see the DEBUG event is logged from main now. The reason you don't see the DEBUG event from function1 is that you don't have a logger configured with qualname "function1", so those events just go up to root logger.

Comment: WOW!  I completely missed what was going on!  Thanks very much for your patience and help

Comment: @jordanthompson Is your issue solved, then? Please have a read of [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)